# Spring AOP Autowiring exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, autowired

I'm using AspectJ in my project.

```
@Aspect
Class FooAsspectj{
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FooAsspectj.class);

@Pointcut("execution(* com.abc.Foo.getFoo(..))")
public void getFoo() { }

@Around("getFoo()")
public Object profileFoo(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    log.debug("Going to call the method.");
    Object output = pjp.proceed();
    log.debug("Method execution completed.");
    long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    log.debug("Method execution time: " + elapsedTime + " milliseconds.");
    return output;

}
```

}

```
 Class Foo{

    public void getFoo(String abc){

System.out.println("Hello Foo");
    }
```

Now I have another class UseFoo, in which I'm autowiring Foo class

```
Class UseFoo{

@Autowired
    private Foo foo;

}
```

I have made following entries in ApplicationContext.xml

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<bean id="fooaspect" class="FooAsspectj" />
```

I'm getting error

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'useFoo':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private Foo
>   UseFoo.foo;
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set
>   Foo field
>   UseFoo.foo to
>   $Proxy56

If I remove `<bean id="fooaspect" class="FooAsspectj" />` it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

This is resolved by using the following

```
 <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```